# GitHub actions: env value in branches names (i.e. on push)

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, github-actions-workflows

I need to run `only` on branches what ends with specified `env` variable.
Let's pretend that we are on `feat/project-name` branch and this is may `workflow.yml`:

```
env:
  PROJECT: project-name

on:
  push:
    # only for branches what ends with given project name
    branches:
      - "**$PROJECT"
```

Above not work. Below, hard coded is OK:

```
env:
  PROJECT: project-name

on:
  push:
    # only for branches what ends with given project name
    branches:
      - "**project-name"
```

Tried with: `"**${{ env.PROJECT }}"` and other configuration and nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure env variables at the workflow level, but you can't use them at that level.

According to the documentation ([reference 1](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#env) and [reference 2](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables)):

> **Environment variables** *(at the workflow level)* are available to the `steps` of all jobs in the workflow.

In your example, the environment variable is used at the workflow level (in the trigger `on` configuration), not inside a job `steps`, and the GitHub interpreter doesn't interpolate the value at that level.

You would need to hardcode the value at that level, or receive it as input (`${{ inputs.value }}`) from another workflow (or from the GitHub API).